# How to align and justify items in a column in flex display using CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, justify

I was trying to create a side menu for my website and I have used flex property for the items in it but they don't look right with the current alignment, so I wanted to change the alignment and its justification but couldn't do it.

I tried different properties like align items, align text, align content, and even justify content and justify items but none of them helped me.

I want to align the items to left and justify it to make it look better.

This is the link of the repository in github: https://github.com/abhishek12221732/Music-Mania.git

[The image of menu I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YSv0.png)

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: If you don't provide any code we can't help you.

Comment: Please share some code, sandbox or something that reproduces your code, so we can help out with the problem try https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
align-items:flex-start;
```

To the flexbox containing the menu (in your code this is the div with the class of "leftmenue". To do this add align-items: flex-start; to this class in your mm.css file.

As other have said, it's best to copy (a piece of) your code here to github so  that people can easier diagnose the problem and help you.